# Mysql 1050 followed by 1051

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1050, mysql-error-1051

Please help me figure this one out. I've already tried deleting and re-creating data files, flushing tables, restarting the database and entire server.

InnoDB is in Force Recovery = 4

```
>mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 3
Server version: 5.5.16 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use wotstats_info_gold;
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table player_team_role ( id int(11) ) ;
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table '`wotstats_info_gold`.`player_team_role`' already exists
mysql> drop table player_team_role;
ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'player_team_role'
mysql> flush tables;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table player_team_role ( id int(11) ) ;
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table '`wotstats_info_gold`.`player_team_role`' already exists
mysql>
```

Comment: Is there something strange going on (permissions etc.) in the data folder for `wotstats_info_gold` (under `/var/lib/mysql/` or wherever)?  What happens if you `DROP` the db?

Comment: No, permissions are all right.

Answer (score 0):

some times this happens having sql-mode PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH